# Append custom class to wordpress headway theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I would like to hack headway theme by adding an option to pages to append custom "classes" for that particular page. It's similar to your regular page where you have an option to select page template. but instead of selecting page template user would just have to select the class he/she wanted to append on the page. that class will have a CSS overide.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<body class=" red ...other headway css classes..." ">
```

**CSS**

```
body.red #container { background: red }
body.green #container { background: green }
```

1. I want to add a custom dropdown that list some classes option for theme to choose. example item on the dropdown. "red theme", "blue theme". This can also be done using Custom field but prefred to use dropdown so user won't get it wrong.
2. Append the class that was selected on the page to the  tag of that page. I tried using "body_class" on my functions.php But It totally erased all the classes causing my page to break appart. What I wanted to do is just append the custom class instead of erasing the entire classes of the body.

Please advice. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Headway already has a custom meta box for custom classes on a page, so maybe you could either:

1. hack that to display a drop down
2. create some sort of meta box that will save a selection from a drop down to the same field that Headway writes to, if that's possible, and just remove/hide the Headway meta box from the admin
3. add an informational box on the page screen that displays the available classes and just use the Headway meta box instead (upgrade safe, best approach to keep things clean)

Comment: Hi Caitlin,

Thank you for your response. I'm looking for a backend solution rather than frontend hack. Because I need the settings to be permanently stored in the DB. I think you were referring on the built in hooks and maybe add a javascript to switch on styles.

thanks!

Comment: the meta options headway providing me is limited. It only allow me to hide navigations, headers and stuff.